# S-Bahn Question

Tags: pronunciation

In the S-Bahn, I keep hearing something like

> Einsatz bitte

or

> Einstein bitte

But I am pretty sure I am misunderstanding the sounds that it is said.

The context is the voice in the S-Bahn right when the doors open. I assume it means

> Beware of the door opening

or something like that, but I am not sure.

Comment: _"Einsatz bitte"_ That probably would apply for Japanese public traffic services :-D.

Comment: ... where _Einstein bitte_ might appeal to the _"collective intelligence"_, what's the right action to do right when the train doors are open. S-Bahn voice requests will always be a complete mystery: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0n0g8S3aA0o

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The context is the voice in the S-Bahn right when the doors open.

The usual request from the *S Bahn voice* when the doors of the train open is

> > **Einsteigen** Bitte!

which means

> > Get in please!

in English.

Comment: In quick speech, this may water down: [ˈaɪnˌʃtaɪɡən ˈbɪtə] → [ˈaɪnˌʃtaɪɡŋ̩ ˈbɪtə] → [ˈaɪnˌʃtaɪŋ ˈbɪtə] → [ˈaɪnˌʃtaɪŋ͡m ˈbɪtə] → [ˈaɪnˌʃtaɪm ˈbɪtə], which is pretty much the same as _Einstein bitte._

Answer (score 3):

As a sidenote to the [correct answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/52601/36160) I'd like to point out that there is sometimes (like in Berlin) a second announcement

> Zurückbleiben bitte!

which translates to

> Stay behind / Keep back

to signal that boarding time is over and passengers should avoid entering because the doors  are closing. (thanks to [Volker Landgraf](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/33644/volker-landgraf))

Comment: Actually both are used in Berlin. *Einsteigen (bitte)* means that the boarding time will **soon** be over, while *Zurückbleiben (bitte)* means that it **is** over and you should stay behind and wait for the next train if you haven't boarded this one yet.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf: reading your comment make me remember it, thanks, I will update

Comment: Never heard the addition "bitte" in Berlin S-Bahn.